# Is cruise speed same for all ships?

Tags: elite-dangerous

Is super-cruise speed and acceleration the same for all ships and modules?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, all ships have the same speed in supercruise.

Maneuverability is the only thing that varies between ships in supercruise.

Comment: So what does manouvrebility in super-cruise depend on? The trusters/ship or on FSD?

Comment: Seems to be mostly per ship model thing.

Comment: the maximum speed in super-cruise you can attain is 2001c (c is the speed of light)